# its neccessary that bucket and athena and quicksight must be in same region in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

AWS Bucket, AWS Athena, AWS Quicksight must be in same region or can be in different region in order to process data?

Answer (score 1):

The Athena [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/getting-started.html) indicates:

> You can query data in regions other than the region where you run
>   Athena. Standard inter-region data transfer rates for Amazon S3 apply
>   in addition to standard Athena charges.

Not 100% sure about QuickSight, though I know it cannot connect to VPC resources cross-region.

As a general rule, I'd try hard to ensure that my analytics tools were in the same region as the data, for both latency and network cost reasons. That might mean considering the cost of cross-region S3 replication.